# Count blanks row by row

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I need an auto-expanding formula to count blank cells in each row, as long as there are values in `B`. I've tried `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(B2:B),IFERROR(1/0),COUNTBLANK(E2:2)))` and thereby managed the expansion, but it keeps counting `E2:2` and not the actual row the array expands to.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(B2:B100),MMULT(N(ISBLANK(B2:100)), TRANSPOSE(column(B2:2)^0)),))
```

Change range to suit.

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you so much! One small question though: I'm trying to change `B2:100` to `B2:B` for flexibility, but get this ERROR: `MMULT has incompatible matrix sizes. Number of columns in first matrix (1) must equal number of rows in second matrix (99).` Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: @ComfortEagle: You should adjust `B2:100` too.

Comment: @Rubén: Thanks for jumping in. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Using INDIRECT to add auto-adjustable references to the formula from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40130152/1595451) by @JPV

```
=ArrayFormula(
  IF(
    LEN(INDIRECT("B2:B"&COUNT(B2:B)+1)),
    MMULT(N(ISBLANK(INDIRECT("B2:"&COUNT(B2:B)+1))), TRANSPOSE(column(B2:2)^0)),
  )
)
```

NOTE: It's assumed that the values in B2:B are numbers or blanks.